# Azure Java SDK - VHD upload

Tags: java, azure, vhd, azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

While trying to upload an VHD file to azure storage through java sdk getting following error

Error :

> Response received. Status code = '400', Request ID =
>   '33ed86f1-0001-0085-383d-c67f28000000', Content-MD5 = 'null', ETag =
>   'null', Date = 'Tue, 14 Jun 2016 13:09:43 GMT'.  Error response
>   received. HttpStatusCode= 400, HttpStatusMessage= The specified blob
>   or block content is invalid., ErrorCode= InvalidBlobOrBlock,
>   ExtendedErrorInformation= {ErrorMessage= The specified blob or block
>   content is invalid..  Checking if the operation should be retried.
>   Retry count = '0', HTTP status code = '400', Error Message = 'The
>   specified blob or block content is invalid.'

.

Comment: Hi, that's your error information, not question. So what the question is? If you want to know the explaination for the error, I think @AlexBelotserkovskiy post has been answered clearly, and you can also refer to the list of blob service error codes at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/Dd179439.aspx for searching. If you want to fix, I think you need to post the code.

Answer (score 1):

That is the issue that may occurs because of different reasons - most of them i encountered were fixed in a matter of time. There is a very good article from  Gaurav Mantri described what can be done to fix that - please check [that](http://gauravmantri.com/2013/05/18/windows-azure-blob-storage-dealing-with-the-specified-blob-or-block-content-is-invalid-error/).
In a short - it may occurs because you tried to upload the same blob a few times in a short time. Try to wait and upload again.

The second thought i had is could you try to upload your VHD as a fixed blob using different methods? For example, [PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-createupload-vhd/) or [azcopy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/). But i do not know the scenario, so it is just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Inaddition to PowerShell/azcopy (those target Windows users), there is also vhd upload tool written in Go lang which is cross-platform. In case you are in Linux and want to try vhd upload, this tool should help you https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-vhd-utils